# Meaning of electric dipole moment

Tags: electrostatics, definition, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

what is the meaning of electric dipole moment?

Or why do we need to define electric dipole moment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/IDfGSC2gfz0?feature=shared  : this might help

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have some irregular charged object and you want to know what will be the electric field it produces at some given point. What is your course of action? First, you can go brute-force and just calculate the field by using some software, or, if the distribution has some useful symmetries,come up with some analytical monster expression.

Alternatively, you can back up and say that you can approximately treat the original irregular body as a point source with total charge $Q$. This approximation actually works increasingly well on the distances sufficiently far away from the charged body. Now you can say the potential $\phi(r) = Q/|r|$ What you have done is actually referred to as $monopole$ approximation.

If you are interested in finding out what are the corrections due to non-spherical nature of the distribution, but you want to do it sequentially, introducing the effects of "non-sphericity" one by one, in the increasing order then what you need is the so-called multipole expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion), in which the dipole moment $\vec{p}$ is but the coefficient in first non-spherical term in the expansion $\phi(r) =Q/|r|+\vec{p}\cdot \vec{r}/|r|^3+...$.

*) You can also think of multipole expansion as an expansion of the potential $\phi(\vec{r})$ over sperical harmonics.

Comment: your explanation begs the reverse question as to what extent does the *full* set of multipoles determine the exact charge distribution.